# Insert timestamp when value copy/paste or inserts/edits whole row in Column C in google sheets, only insert to blank cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- I'm trying to insert a timestamp into a cell in column B that has the same row index as the edited or pasted value in column C. Also, I only want to insert a timestamp in an empty cell in column B, while the skip cell already has a timestamp.
- This code works correctly whether I edit a cell in column C or paste a value in column C when all cells in column B are empty.
- This code has issues with overwriting or not writing values when pasting multiple cells. Kindly help me in editing it.
- Here is sample sheet: **[insert timestamp - multi cell - check blank cell](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BGu4_3bdEwl_9VhWiLVbPbHzvqy4LlPW0RcpV9LnyHs/edit?usp=sharing)**

```js
function insert_timestamp(e) 
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = s.getActiveCell();
  var r = e.range;
  var firstRow = r.getRow();
  var numRows = r.getNumRows();
  var firstCol = r.getColumn();
  var lastCol = r.getLastColumn();
  var datecell = s.getRange(cell.getRowIndex(), 2);
  if((firstCol == 3 || lastCol == 3) && s.getName() == 'test' && datecell.isBlank()) {

    var destRange = s.getRange(firstRow, 2, numRows);
    var dates = new Array(numRows).fill([new Date()]);
    destRange.setValues(dates).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the date to column "B" when column "C" is edited.
- In this case, you want to put the date, when the column "B" is empty.
- Function of `insert_timestamp` is installed as OnEdit trigger.

In order to check the values of columns "B" and "C", I retrieved the values from the columns of edited rows. And, I thought that the event object can be used for your situation. From these points, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function insert_timestamp(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if ((range.columnStart == 3 || range.columnEnd == 3) && sheet.getSheetName() == 'test') {
    var values = range.offset(0, -1, range.rowEnd - range.rowStart + 1, 2).getDisplayValues();
    var rangeList = values.reduce((ar, [b, c], i) => {
      if (b == "") ar.push("B" + (i + range.rowStart));
      // if (b == "" && c != "") ar.push("B" + (i + range.rowStart));
      return ar;
    }, []);
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  }
}
```

- If you don't want to put the date to the column "B" when the column "C" is empty, please use `if (b == "" && c != "") ar.push("B" + (i + range.rowStart));` instead of `if (b == "") ar.push("B" + (i + range.rowStart));`.

#### Note:

- **This sample script is run by the OnEdit trigger. So when you directly run this function, an error occurs. Please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks a lot! Your first code is working exactly as I needed.

Comment: @brianphamx Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hi Tanaikie,I have a small suggestion to improve this piece of code: I want to get the column's title to refer to the column, and I want to ensure that when the column is inserted, the script still works properly.
- Could you please advise me on how to proceed?

Comment: @brianphamx About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. And also, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question. I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, I had new post on this thread to explain more about what I need to do. Can you help me check this

Comment: @brianphamx I would like to support you. But you are posting your question as an answer. Please delete it and please post it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question. I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I post new question here. Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797546/insert-timestamp-when-value-copy-paste-or-inserts-edits-whole-row-in-google-shee

Comment: @brianphamx Thank you for replying. I will check it. And, please delete your answer posted as the answer.

Comment: I have delete my answer. Could you check my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797546/insert-timestamp-when-value-copy-paste-or-inserts-edits-whole-row-in-google-shee

Comment: @brianphamx I checked your new question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797546/insert-timestamp-when-value-copy-paste-or-inserts-edits-whole-row-in-google-shee I noticed that your new question has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Comment: Yeah Tanaike, I'm trying improve function speed cuz when multi row change my function need to repeat original code -> function process to slow. can you help me?

Comment: @brianphamx Thank you for replying. About your new question of `Yeah Tanaike, I'm trying improve function speed cuz when multi row change my function need to repeat original code -> function process to slow. can you help me?`, I woluld like to support you. But that is different from your this question. So can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. And also, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question. I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?