# Insert timestamp when value copy/paste or inserts/edits whole row in google sheets, only insert to blank cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- I'm trying to insert a timestamp into a cell in "timestamp" column that has the same row index as the edited or pasted value in "status" column . Also, I only want to insert a timestamp in an empty cell in "timestamp" column, while the skip cell already has a timestamp.
- Issue: When I add or remove columns, the positions of the "timestamp" and "status" columns change, causing the code to fail. I'm seeking for a solution to make this code work properly when the "timestamp" and "status" columns' index change.
  I'm trying to use column header in code instead of column's index.

Also I want to convert timestamp to number like yymmddHHmmss*1000 + seri number column "No."
Exp: timestamp 22:01:20 14:08:05 and seri number column "No." is 678 then the value I want to insert into column "id" is 2201201408050678.

```js
function insert_timestamp(e) {
  //get range
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  // get header
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var editcol = headers[0].indexOf("Status") + 1;
  var timestampcol = headers[0].indexOf("Timestamp") + 1;

  if ((range.columnStart == editcol || range.columnEnd == editcol) && sheet.getSheetName() == 'CONTENT.ORDER') {
    var values = range.offset(0, -1, range.rowEnd - range.rowStart + 1, 2).getDisplayValues();
    var rangeList = values.reduce((ar, [b, c], i) => {
      if (b == "" &&  c =="Approved") ar.push("b" + (i + range.rowStart));
      return ar;
    }, []);
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of how your sheet looks?

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou sure you can check here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kXlH6fnCWLAV8Q-FEiSOXpuUqgCGe0cgLLDd_zLgmaM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != 'CONTENT.ORDER') return;

  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  var col_header = sheet.getRange(1,col).getValue();
  if (col_header != 'Status') return;
  if (e.value != 'Approved') return;

  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var timestamp_col = headers.indexOf('Timestamp') + 1;
  var num_col = headers.indexOf('No.') + 1;
  var id_col = headers.indexOf('ID') + 1;

  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  var timestamp_cell = sheet.getRange(row, timestamp_col);
  if (timestamp_cell.getValue() !== '') return;

  var tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  timestamp_cell.setValue(timestamp).setNumberFormat('yy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss');

  var num = sheet.getRange(row,num_col).getValue().toString().padStart(4,'0');
  var id = timestamp.replace(/\D/g,'') + num;
  var id_cell = sheet.getRange(row,id_col);
  id_cell.setValue(id);
}
```

**Update**

Here is the variant of the function that handles a range of selected (adjoined) cells:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != 'CONTENT.ORDER') return;

  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  var col_header = sheet.getRange(1,col).getValue();
  if (col_header != 'Status') return;

  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var timestamp_col = headers.indexOf('Timestamp') + 1;
  var num_col = headers.indexOf('No.') + 1;
  var id_col = headers.indexOf('ID') + 1;

  var row_start = e.range.rowStart;
  var row_end = e.range.rowEnd;
  if (sheet.getRange(row_start,col).getValue() != 'Approved') return;

  var tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

  for (let row = row_start; row <= row_end; row++) {

    var timestamp_cell = sheet.getRange(row, timestamp_col);
    if (timestamp_cell.getValue() !== '') continue;
    timestamp_cell.setValue(timestamp).setNumberFormat('yy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss');

    var num = sheet.getRange(row,num_col).getValue().toString().padStart(4,'0');
    var id = timestamp.replace(/\D/g,'') + num;
    var id_cell = sheet.getRange(row,id_col);

    id_cell.setValue(id);
  }
}
```

Basically it just repeats the original function for every selected cell. It does the job, but not too fast. It can be improved if you need to deal with too many rows.

Comment: Yeh it work correctly when single "status" cell change, but when multi "status" cell change it not working. Like when i', trying to paste 'Approved' value into C2:C5 nothing happen. Can you help me slove this?

Comment: Hi @brianphamx ! I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @Yuri Khiristich, I've test your code, it work perfectly. Yeah and it should be improve to deal with 15 more row. I'm truying to work with array before set value to cell. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: The solution is obvious, yes, to get a 2D array with all selected rows, to process the array within a script and set back on the sheet all at once. I can try to code it in a couple days (I'm a little busy now). Only thing I need to know -- the range of selected rows will it always adjoined rows? Or there can be non-adjoined ranges sometimes?

Comment: sorry i'm non-tech guy so is non-adjoined ranges like when I'm trying to paste value into C3:C5 and C8:C10 at the same time. if my understanding correct then yes there can be non-adjoined ranges sometimes.

Comment: Hi. It seems I'm still too busy and I got the flu. You can take my code an ask a new question: how to make the code work faster and how to handle non-adjoined ranges. I think you will get the answer from locals faster than from me. I'm sorry

Comment: it's ok Yuri thank you so much. your code working well. that help me so much.

Comment: Some interesting news... I failed to made the script to work with non-adjacent ranges. Technically it should work, here is the docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection#getActiveRangeList() But actually the trigger `onEdit()` takes only one of selected ranges (first one usually but sometimes even not first one) and ignores the rest ranges. Perhap I don't know something. So there are two options: (a) don't use `onEdit()` and run script via the custom menu, or (b) don't use non-adjacent ranges. Let me know what you think